ValueError: The field xxxxxx was declared with a lazy reference to 'aaa.bbb', but app 'aaa' doesn't provide model 'bbb'
Estoy trabajando con usuario, y cuando hago la migración me aparece el siguiente mensaje en la consola:

"C:\Users\56954\Envs\praxis\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 637, in __init__
raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'web.usuario', but app 'web' doesn't provide model 'usuario'.


Pulsa en [edit] y pon un [repro] del problema en cuestión. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además, lee el mensaje de error: ¿existe el modelo usuario en tu app (módulo) llamado web?

Hola Donni, para evitar votos negativos y/o que cierren tu pregunta, te sugiero que la edites, y agregues el código pertinente.
